# count:293 Uncaught ReferenceError: connectMetamask is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, blockchain, metamask

So this function should connect `Metamask` wallet to a website. Yet no matter what I do it always throws the same error:

> connectMetamask is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick;

Please help me fix this.

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <script>
    let account;
    const connectMetamask = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts"
        });
        account = accounts[0];
        document.getElementById("connect-button").innerHTML = `Account is: ${account}`;
        }
      }
</script>
<button id="connect-button" onclick="connectMetamask()">Connect Metamask</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Your `connectMetamask` is an `async` call that will `await` the response. That is, as the error message reads, its value will not exist immediately. Rather than using an inline `onclick`, you might want to create an event listener that will initiate _after_ the `await` response resolves.